# How to access ArrayList from another class

Tags: java, class, user-interface, arraylist

OK i have multiple Java files but only looking at 2 at the moment and i am doing a GUI program. 
I have an arraylist of Landlords in one file with a getLandlords method that returns the array and it won't work eclipse just gives an error no matter what i try
File 1

```
package assignment2;


import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class RealEstateManage extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    RealEstateManage theGUI = new RealEstateManage();

}

//Initial setup for base of GUI
private JFrame jfFrame;
private JButton jbAddLandlord, jbAddProperty, jbAddLease, jbRecord, jbMaintenance, jbDisplayproperty;
private JTextArea jtaResults;
private JTextField jtfinput1, jtfinput2, jtfinput3, jtfinput4;
private JList <Landlord> jlLandlord;
private Vector<Landlord> vlist = new Vector<Landlord>();
private JPanel jpButtons = setupButtons(), jpResults = setupResults();
public RealEstateAgency R = new RealEstateAgency();


public RealEstateManage()
{
    jfFrame = new JFrame ();
    jfFrame.add(jpButtons, "North");
    jfFrame.add(jpResults,"West");

    jfFrame.setSize(900, 400);
    jfFrame.setLocation(400, 300);
    jfFrame.setTitle("Real Estate Management");
    jfFrame.setVisible(true);
}


//Setup the buttons at the top of the GUI
public JPanel setupButtons()
{
    JPanel jp = new JPanel ();

    jbAddLandlord = new JButton("Add New Landlord");
    jbAddProperty = new JButton("Add New Property");
    jbAddLease = new JButton("Add New Lease");
    jbRecord = new JButton("Record Payment");
    jbMaintenance = new JButton("Maintenance");
    jbDisplayproperty = new JButton("Display Properties");

    jp.add(jbAddLandlord); 
    jp.add(jbAddProperty); 
    jp.add(jbAddLease); 
    jp.add(jbRecord); 
    jp.add(jbMaintenance); 
    jp.add(jbDisplayproperty);

    jbAddLandlord.addActionListener(this);
    jbAddProperty.addActionListener(this);
    jbAddLease.addActionListener(this);
    jbRecord.addActionListener(this);
    jbMaintenance.addActionListener(this);
    jbDisplayproperty.addActionListener(this);

    return jp;
}

public JPanel setupResults()
{
    JPanel jp = new JPanel ();


    vlist.add(new Landlord("Fred Jones", "23 Hamilton Road", "0458 789 456", 456123369));

    jtfinput1 = new JTextField (10);
    jtfinput2 = new JTextField (10);
    jtfinput3 = new JTextField (10);
    jtfinput4 = new JTextField (10);

    ArrayList<Landlord> Alist = R.getLandlords();

    jlLandlord = new JList<Landlord>(vlist);
    jlLandlord.addListSelectionListener(this);
    jlLandlord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));

    JLabel jlResults = new JLabel ("Output!");

    jtaResults = new JTextArea (18, 30);
    jtaResults.setEnabled(false);



    jp.add(jlLandlord);
    jp.add(jlResults);
    jp.add(jtaResults);


    return jp;
}


//List Events
@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


//Button Action Events
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
// Button Events

    if(ae.getSource() == jbAddLandlord)
    {
        addLandlord();
    }
    if(ae.getSource() == jbAddLandlord)
    {

    }


}

//Add landlord function
public void addLandlord()
{
    boolean inputIsOk = true;
    String stName, stAddress, stNum, stBank;
    long bank = 0;

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
    myPanel.add(jtfinput1);
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Address:"));
    myPanel.add(jtfinput2);
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Phone:"));
    myPanel.add(jtfinput3);
    myPanel.add(new JLabel("Bank Account: (8-10 Digits)"));
    myPanel.add(jtfinput4);



    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
           "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        stName = jtfinput1.getText();
        stAddress = jtfinput2.getText();
        stNum = jtfinput3.getText();
        stBank = jtfinput4.getText();
        try{bank = Long.valueOf(stBank).longValue();                
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            inputIsOk = false;              
        }
        if (inputIsOk = true){
            R.addLandlord(new Landlord(stName, stAddress, stNum, bank));
        }

    }
   // jlLandlord.updateUI();

}



}
```

FILE 2

```
package assignment2;

import java.util.*;

// The RealEstateAgency class is intended to be the central place to go to for finding
// a landlord that the system "knows" about. 

public class RealEstateAgency {
private ArrayList<Landlord> allLandlords;       // A way of collecting all the Landlords

public RealEstateAgency()
{
    // prepare the agency for future landlords...
    allLandlords = new ArrayList<Landlord>();
    addLandlord(new Landlord("stName", "stAddress", "stNum", 12456897));
    System.out.println(getLandlords());
}

// Method to note the provided Landlord, by adding it to the RealEstateAgency's internal ArrayList.
// Returns true if apparently successful, false if something goes wrong such as the landlord already being present.
public boolean addLandlord(Landlord whoToStore)
{
    boolean success = false;

    if (whoToStore == null)         // ensure there is actually a parameter
        success = false;
    else {
        if (allLandlords.contains(whoToStore))      // landlord already in the list
            success = false;
        else
        {                                           // Landlord not yet in list
            allLandlords.add(whoToStore);           // So add this landlord
            success = true;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

// Method to obtain a landlord from the RealEstateAgency's collection of known landlords,
// by providing the full name. If no such landlord exists, null will be returned.
public Landlord getLandlord(String fullName)
{
    Landlord current = null;
    boolean found = false;
    int index = 0;

    while ((!found) && (index < allLandlords.size()))
    {
        current = allLandlords.get(index);
        if (current.getFullName().equals(fullName))
            found = true;
        else
            index++;
    }

    // If we get to here, and "found" is true, then "current" will be the matching Landlord

    if (!found)                 // did not find a match
        current = null;         // so ensure we return no Landlord

    return current;
}


// Method to obtain an ArrayList containing the same landlords as those which the
// RealEstateAgency knows about (but without exposing the inner ArrayList object
// so that any alterations made to the returned ArrayList won't impact the RealEstateAgency)
public ArrayList<Landlord> getLandlords()
{
    ArrayList<Landlord> duplicate;
    duplicate = (ArrayList<Landlord>) allLandlords.clone();     

    return duplicate;
}

public ArrayList<Landlord> getLandlords1()
{
    return allLandlords;
}

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

The Issues i am having is in the setupResults() function and the getLandlords() function

Thanks in advance

LANDLORD CODE

```
package assignment2;

import java.util.*;

// The Landlord class allows you to create objects that encapsulate the key data 
// about each Landlord, as well as the information about all the properties that 
// they make available for rent (some of which may have current leases active). 

public class Landlord {
private String fullName;        // The name of the landlord
private String address;         // Where the landlord lives!
private String phone;           // allow for spaces in number
private long bankAccount;       // To permit 10 digits, requires the 'long' data type

private ArrayList<Property> myProperties;       // All properties owned by this landlord

public Landlord(String fullName, String address, String phone, long bankAccount)
{
    // Simply store the parameters into the fields...
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.bankAccount = bankAccount;

    // prepare for future leases...
    myProperties = new ArrayList<Property>();
}

// ACCESSORS for each field of basic information

public String getFullName()
{
    return fullName;
}

public String getAddress()
{
    return address;
}

public String getPhone()
{
    return phone;
}

public long getBankAccount()
{
    return bankAccount;
}

// Method to note/store another Property, where this Landlord is considered the owner of the property.
// It returns true if successfully added to the list of properties belonging to this landlord.
public boolean addProperty(Property theProperty)
{
    boolean result;
    if (theProperty == null)        // if it is null, we ignore this method call.
        result = false;
    else if (!myProperties.contains(theProperty)){  // Make sure it is not already in the array list
        myProperties.add(theProperty);
        result = true;
    }
    else                            // This means w have already added the property, so cannot add it again.
        result = false;

    return result;
}

// Method to return an iterator that may be used to cycle over all leases involving this landlord.
public Iterator<Property> getPropertiesIterator()
{
    return myProperties.iterator();
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Landlord: " + fullName;
}
}
```

PROPERTY CODE

```
package assignment2;

// The Property class encapsulates the basic information about one property the system knows 
// about: essentially the address of the property, and a reference to the Lease details of the property.

public class Property {
private String propertyAddress;
private Lease currentLease;                 // When null, there is no active lease (it is available).

public Property(String address)
{
    this.propertyAddress = address;
    this.currentLease = null;               // Initially, nobody is leasing it.
}

public String getPropertyAddress()
{
    return propertyAddress;
}

// no mutator for address, because it won't ever change.

// Method to return the current lease's details.
public Lease getCurrentLease()
{
    return currentLease;
}

// Method to set the current Lease of this Property.
// If null is provided, the property will not have any Lease assigned to it;
// otherwise, the provided Lease will be recorded as describing the relationship for this property.
public void setCurrentLease(Lease newLease)
{
    currentLease = newLease;
}

// Method to report whether or not this property is currently associated with a lease (regardless
// of whether fully paid or not)
public boolean isLeased()
{
    if (currentLease == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Property: " + propertyAddress;
}
}
```

LEASE CODE

```
package assignment2;

import java.util.*;

// The Lease class encapsulates information about an individual lease of a property by a tenant. 
// The data stored here includes all the tenant’s details (name, phone number) as well as 
// characteristics of the lease itself such as the duration, the weekly rent amount, how long
// remains in terms of payments, what maintenance has occurred.

public class Lease {
private String tenantFullName;  // The name of the person who is living in the leased property.
private String tenantPhone;     // Contact number for the person. Allow a leading zero at start, spaces between sections.
private int rentRate;           // The amount of rent to be paid each week.
private int leasePeriod;        // Either 6 or 12, being a 6 month or 12 month agreement
private int weeksRemaining;     // How many weeks remain to be paid for. Initially 26 or 52.
private ArrayList<Maintenance> maintenanceRecord;       // record of all maintenance during life of lease

// Create a new lease, recording the following details:
// - tenantName:  records the name of the person living in the property
// - tenantPhone: records a contact phone number for the tenant
// - rentRate:    the amount of rent which is to be paid each week.
// - leasePeriod: Either 6 or 12, indicating the number of months the lease is to last for.  
public Lease(String tenantName, String tenantPhone, int rentRate, int leasePeriod)
{
    this.tenantFullName = tenantName;
    this.tenantPhone = tenantPhone;
    this.rentRate = rentRate;

    if (leasePeriod == 12 || leasePeriod == 6)      // Check validity of parameter
        this.leasePeriod = leasePeriod;
    else                                            // if not valid, set to default of 6 month.
        this.leasePeriod = 6;

    // Determine (automatically) how many weeks the lease is for, and set as initial value
    // for the 'weeksRemaining' field:
    if (this.leasePeriod == 12)
        this.weeksRemaining = 52;           // a Year remains to be paid for
    else
        this.weeksRemaining = 26;           // Only half a year remains to be paid for.

    // Prepare the lease for future Maintenance records...
    maintenanceRecord = new ArrayList<Maintenance>();
}

// ACCESSORS

public String getTenantFullName()
{
    return tenantFullName;
}

public String getTenantPhone()
{
    return tenantPhone;
}

public int getRentRate()
{
    return rentRate;
}

public int getLeasePeriod()
{
    return leasePeriod;
}

public int getWeeksRemaining()
{
    return weeksRemaining;
}

// Method to reduce the number of weeks remaining to be paid over the period of the lease.
// If the parameter is in excess of the current number of remaining weeks, the method will
// return false, otherwise it returns true and adjusts the number of remaining weeks.
public boolean reduceWeeksRemaining(int howMuch)
{
    boolean result;
    if (howMuch > weeksRemaining)
        result = false;
    else
    {
        weeksRemaining -= howMuch;      // Reduces how many weeks remain unpaid.
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

// Method to add another maintenance information record to this lease's list of maintenance records. 
public void noteMaintenance(String reason, double cost)
{
    Maintenance maintInfo = new Maintenance(reason,cost);
    maintenanceRecord.add(maintInfo);
}

// Method to return an Iterator that may be used to cycle over all maintenance records for this lease
public Iterator<Maintenance> getMaintenanceRecords()
{
    return maintenanceRecord.iterator();
}
}
```

MAINTENANCE CODE

```
package assignment2;

// The Maintenance class is used to represent an individual occurrence of Maintenance 
// and records the cost and description of the maintenance.

public class Maintenance {
private String reason;
private double cost;

public Maintenance(String reason, double cost)
{
    this.reason = reason;
    this.cost = cost;
}

// ACCESSORS:

public String getReason()
{
    return reason;
}

public double getCost()
{
    return cost;
}

// Gives a explanation of the cost and reason represented by this Maintenance object.
public String toString()
{
    return "$" + cost + " for " + reason;
}
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: You have the function defined as `public Landlord getLandlord(String fullName)` which returns a `Landlord` not an `ArrayList<Landlord>`!

Comment: @AlvinBunk scroll down. There is getLandlords() and getLandlords1()

Comment: The errors i get are:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment2.RealEstateManage.setupResults(RealEstateManage.java:87)
 at assignment2.RealEstateManage.<init>(RealEstateManage.java:29)
 at assignment2.RealEstateManage.main(RealEstateManage.java:18)


and i added getLandlords1() as a test but it still wouldn't work

Comment: and what line is line 87?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correctly compiled code?

Comment: Are there errors in your FILE2 in the function `public ArrayList<Landlord> getLandlords()` at all? You have the line `ArrayList<Landlord> duplicate;` which might need to be initialized. Try setting it to null or just duplicate on the same line.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I think Line 87 is `ArrayList<Landlord> Alist = R.getLandlords();`. If you copy that code, that's what I see as Line 87.

Comment: line 87 is ArrayList<Landlord> Alist = R.getLandlords(); and there are no errors in FILE2, tried setting it to NULL and it did the same thing

Comment: @Chris I just read through this. If this is all the code there is and you left nothing away then in setupResults there is nothing that would throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, try running in Debug mode, set a breakpoint at Line 87 and then do a "Step Into" (F5). I'll see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Do you have the Landlord code Chris?

Comment: I also don't think this posting deserves 3 downvotes - whoever did that...

Comment: @Alvin Added all the code for the project even though most of it isn't used yet

Comment: Chris, mark Angelo's answer as the correct answer so he gets bonus points ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you initialize `setupResults()` before `R`.

change:

```
private JPanel jpButtons = setupButtons(), jpResults = setupResults();
public RealEstateAgency R = new RealEstateAgency();


public RealEstateManage()
{
```

to

```
private JPanel jpButtons;
private JPanel jpResults;
public RealEstateAgency R = new RealEstateAgency();


public RealEstateManage()
{
    jpButtons  = setupButtons();
    jpResults = setupResults();
```

As a sidenote:
You take the result as:

```
ArrayList<Landlord> Alist = R.getLandlords();
```

but never use that value.
Maybe you meant to write:

```
ArrayList<Landlord> Alist = R.getLandlords();

jlLandlord = new JList<Landlord>(Alist.toArray(new Landlord[0]));
                                 ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but you did not.

Comment: when i do this i get the error: The constructor JList<Landlord>(ArrayList<Landlord>) is undefined
at assignment2.RealEstateManage.setupResults(RealEstateManage.java:89)

Comment: @Chris Meh. Fixed. I always forget that JLists doesn't like collections.

Comment: tried that error is now: The constructor JList<Landlord>(Object[]) is undefined

Comment: This isn't why the error is occurring @AngeloNeuschitzer.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yeah, I know. But it could cause it to go away non the less if it causes the OP to recompile his code. As this question should be closed anyway it won't matter so much.

Comment: @Chris I found your problem, see my update.

Comment: This is the fix Chris! I tried it too and it works! I upped your answer Angelo.